# Flow types and Polymorphism

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

The component below takes a `fields` array of `Field` objects. The `Field` class is extended by `SelectboxField` (and other fields, but that's the one in the code so far). The component determines the type of field and renders the specific component for that field. The specific component, say the `SelectboxFieldView` takes as a prop the specific type of field (`SelectboxField`).

```js
// @flow
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import Field from "../models/fields/Field";
import SelectboxFieldView from "../components/SelectboxFieldView";
import SelectboxField from "../models/fields/SelectboxField";

type Props = { fields: Field[] };
type State = {};

class FieldsRenderer extends Component<Props, State> {
  render() {
    const MockFields = [
      this.props.fields.find(f => f.type === "selectbox") || new Field()
    ]; 

    // const fields = this.props.fields
    const fields = MockFields
    return (
      <View>
        {fields.map((field, i: number) => {
          switch (field.constructor) {
            case SelectboxField:
              const selField: SelectboxField = field;  // ERROR HERE
              return <SelectboxFieldView key={i} field={selField} />;
            default:
              return <Text key={i}>A Field</Text>;
          }
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default FieldsRenderer;
```

I get a flow error on the line I've indicated, on the word `field`, saying:

```
Cannot assign field to selField because Field is incompatible with SelectField`
```

This error is there with or without the explicit type definition of `selField`.

I've also tried a Type Casting expression:

```js
 switch (field.constructor) {
            case SelectboxField:
              (field: SelectboxField);
              return <SelectboxFieldView key={i} field={field} />;
```

But it says "Cannot cast field to SelectboxField because Field is incompatible with SelectboxField`

That doesn't seem right:

```js
// @flow

class Field {
  title: string;
  type: string;

  static fromApiFormInfo(formInfo: Object): Field {
    const field = new Field();
    field.title = formInfo.title;
    field.type = formInfo.type;
    return field;
  }
}

export default Field;
```

```js
// @flow
import Field from "./Field";

class SelectboxField extends Field {
  placeholder: string;
  options: string[];

  static fromApiFormInfo(formInfo: Object): SelectboxField {
    const base = new SelectboxField();
    const baseField = super.fromApiFormInfo(formInfo);
    const field: SelectboxField = Object.assign(base, { ...baseField });
    field.options = formInfo.options;
    field.placeholder = formInfo.placeholder_text;
    return field;
  }
}

export default SelectboxField;
```

Is there a way to manage this?

Comment: Your error mentions `SelectField`, but your posts here are all about `SelectboxField`. Is that an issue somehow? It could be great if you could trim down an example that can reproduce in https://flow.org/try/.

Comment: Must have been a typo on my part in transcribing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (field.constructor) {
  case SelectboxField:
```

is not something that Flow can process as a [type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/) in order to understand that `field` is a `SelectboxField`. You'll want to do

```
if (field instanceof SelectboxField) {
  return <SelectboxFieldView key={i} field={field} />;
} else {
  return <Text key={i}>A Field</Text>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! That's too bad since the `switch` is so much cleaner.